$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ipx/\hbar} / (p^2 + \beta^2)\, dp $ has two different results.
I tried to evaluate the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}px/\hbar} \over
p^2 + \beta^2}\,{\rm d}p\quad
\mbox{through}\ Contour\ Integration.
$$

The integrand has two simple poles namely $p=i\beta$ and $p=-i\beta$.
First I took a semi-circular contour in the upper-half plane and closed the pole $p=+i\beta$ and using the Cauchy's Residue Theorem I found the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ipx/\hbar} / (p^2 +
\beta^2)\, dp = (\pi/\beta)e^{-\beta x/\hbar}
$$
Then, I took a semi-circular contour in the lower-half plane and closed the pole $p=-i\beta$ and using the Cauchy's Residue Theorem I found the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ipx/\hbar} / (p^2 + \beta^2)\, dp = (\pi/\beta)e^{+\beta x/\hbar}
$$

How is that I am getting two different functions for the same integral ?.
I am unable to find out where I am making mistake.
I would be extremely thankful for resolving my query.

Cauchy's residue theorem basically applies to a closed curve. To apply this to the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ via the limit of semicircle, you have to check whether the integral over the semicircle you introduced vanishes as the radius goes to infinity. In your case, if $x > 0$, the integral along the upper semicircle vanishes whereas the one along the lower semicircle does not. (When $x<0$, the opposite is true.)

@Sangchul Lee  I now understand where I was making mistake and thanks for resolving my query.

For checking: if $w=a+ib$ with $b>0$ then for $t>0$ we have
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{R}e^{itx}\times\frac{b dx}{(x-a)^2+b^2}=e^{itw}.$$ Proof: $$y=\frac{x-a}{b},\ \frac{1}{1+y^2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{R}e^{ity-|t|}dt$$ and Fourier inversion formula.

Can you please elaborate. I could not get what you are trying to convey.

I was offering a way to check your results. Indeed, if $w=a+ib$ with $b>0$ the Cauchy distribution $c_w(dx)=\frac{b}{\pi}\frac{dx}{(x-a)^2+b^2}$ has characteristic function $e^{iwt}$ for $t>0$. This implies that the characteristic function of $c_wc_{w_1}$ (with $w_1=a_1+ib_1$) is $e^{it(w+w_1)}$ for $t>0$, implying a short proof of $c_wc_{w_1}=c_{w+w_1}$ instead of this painful proof by partial fractions.
